# Python Flask - How to redirect a user to the post they just posted?

Tags: python, flask

I'm learning Python and Flask and I've come to a point where I don't really know how to proceed with my app. I have it all in my head, but I just don't have the coding skills as of yet to do everything I imagined. Now I want to redirect the user to the post they created right after posting it. This is what I have for now:

```
@app.route('/forum/announcements/post', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def post():
    if 'loggedin' in session:
         if request.method == "POST" and 'loggedin' in session and 'title' in request.form and 'message' in request.form:
            title = request.form['title']
            message = (request.form['message'])
            author = session['username']
            if title == '':
                flash('Your message needs a title!')
                redirect(url_for('post'))
            elif message == '':
                flash("You didn't write anything!")
                redirect(url_for('post'))
            elif len(title) > 50:
                flash('The title can only be up to 50 characters long!')
                redirect(url_for('post'))
            elif len(title) < 3:
                flash('The title must have at least 3 characters!')
                redirect(url_for('post'))
            elif len(message) < 3:
                flash('Your message must have at least 3 characters!')
                redirect(url_for('post'))
            elif len(message) > 3000:
                flash('Your message can be up to 3000 characters long!')
                redirect(url_for('post'))
            else:
                cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO posts_announcements(title, message, author) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (title, message, author))
                mysql.connection.commit()
                cursor.execute("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();")
                new_post_id = cursor.fetchone()
                flash("Your message has been submitted!")
                return redirect(url_for('posts', id=new_post_id, username=session['username']))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('announcements_desc'))
    return render_template('post.html', username=session['username'])
```

I get the data to the database and then I can display it with this code:

```
@app.route('/forum/announcements/posts/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def posts(id):
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        result = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM posts_announcements WHERE id = %s", [id])
        post = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.close()
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        result1 = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM comments_announcements ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datum_kreacije) DESC")
        comment = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        if request.method == 'POST' and 'comment' in request.form:
            comment1 = request.form['comment']
            author = session['username']
            cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO comments_announcements(message, author) VALUES (%s, %s)", (comment1, author))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            return render_template('posts.html', post=post, comment=comment, username=session['username'])
        return render_template('posts.html', post=post, comment=comment, username=session['username'])
    else:
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        result = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM posts_announcements WHERE id = %s", [id])
        post = cursor.fetchone()
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        result1 = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM comments_announcements ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_of_creation) DESC")
        comment = cur.fetchone()
        return render_template('posts.html', post=post, comment=comment)
```

I can't display the comments, but that's another story. Now I have a different problem. I want the user to be redirected to their post id after posting. But I don't know how to redirect them, when I try adding anything else to redirect I get this error: "TypeError: url_for() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"
Currently the user gets redirected to the posts page, but it's empty.

As stated before in my other question, I'm a complete beginner and any advice will come in handy. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I edited the first code as @NavaneethaKrishnan advised me to, but the posts page is still empty.

Comment: can you show how you've tried to redirect? say, how you've called the url_for() function?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `redirect(url_for('posts', id=new_post_id))`.

But how can get the new id?
Once you add the data into the MySQL, you should get the `id` for the particular row. If you can get the id, we can redirect to that post. This can be achieved by `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function.

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (...);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

This will give you the `primary key`.

Here is my output,
[image]

Comment: I believe you pointed me in the right direction with LAST_INSERT_ID(), but how am I supposed to use it? Should I add a new variable called new_post_id? And what should I assign it to? Sorry, I'm new to all this.

Comment: Yes. 1st run the insert query. Then run the select query. Assign some variable name like `new_post_id = cur.fectchone()` this will fetch the id from the select query.

Comment: Could you please check my code again after I edited it? I suppose I'm not doing it right because the post page is still empty after posting

Comment: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM posts_announcements` remove this. Only `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Comment: You are also closing the connection before the executing the select comment. please remove that

Comment: What am I supposed to do with HTML? How to redirect to the post id? I tried with {{ new_post_id.id }} but I get an error new_post_id is undefined. And if I try to define it before I can't execute the LAST_INSERT_ID() command. Thanks for your help mister @NavaneethaKrishnan, but I can't get this to work

Comment: Okay, I resolved the new_post_id is undefined error, but I still get redirected to the empty posts page

Comment: for HTML, no need to do anything. Only thing is to check whether you can able to get the last_insert_id. Open mysql terminal, 1st run insert query and then `select last_insert_id()`. immediately u should get the id. Check this and let me know

Comment: i added the terminal output in the answer. check that

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying, but I switched to SQLAlchemy. Now I can easily define new relationships between models and add/remove them instantly with Flask-Admin